# Computing the derivative of $f(x) = x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ from the definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I am attempting to find the derivative of a function from the definition of a derivative

The function is:
$$f(x) = x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

I know that my final derivative should look like
$$f'(x) = 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}$$

I found the one half of the solution near the bottom of my posted attempt but I am not sure how to simplify the other half of the solution to look like $-\cos\frac{1}{x}$

I understand it is very unconventional to compute this complex of a function, but this was on my professor's testable exercises question set, so it would be very helpful if I could receive some assistance in this department. I am not allowed to use L'Hopital's use or any differentiation rules.

My Attempt:
[image: My Initial Attempt]

Comment: What properties of $ \sin $, $ \cos $ are you allowed to use? Perhaps some well-known limits?

Comment: Anything that is not circular. Trigonometric Identities and well known limits such are fair game

Comment: Then I would suggest the formula for the difference of two sines and $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $.

Comment: Assuming $f(0)$ is defined to be $0$, note that finding $f'(0)$ is less complicated. You'd have $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h\sin(1/h)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-x^2\sin\frac1x}{h}=x^2\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-\sin\frac1x}{h}$$
Now use the trig identity for $\sin(A)-\sin(B)$:
$$\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$$

$$2x^2\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\cos\left(\frac{2x+h}{2x(x+h)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}\right)=2x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\sin\left(\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}\right)$$

That last expression can be written:
$$-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2x(x+h)}{h}\sin\left(\frac{h}{2x(x+h)}\right)$$

Can you take it from here?